# Case Auto-Response sending from wrong email/name

Tags: case-auto-response

I have a Case Auto-Response rule that is sending from the wrong email. For the particular Rule Entry I have it set to send from "Customer Service" and service@mydomain.org. But when I receive the email I get it from my name and from noreply@salesforce.com.

Any idea what causes that? The email content is correct, just the 'from' address is wrong.

Comment: Check the value in My Settings | Settings | Email | My Email Settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Email Deliverability settings in your Salesforce org. I'm attaching a link here how to do that. This should be resolved by following the steps as mentioned. If still not able to fix it, let me know I'll help further.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000167022&type=1